# How do I update multiple table column value of database using textboxes in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

Here is my code. But It is not working on multiple update of table values, It only does work when I update a single value. please help me, im newbie here :(

```
  Private Sub SaveChanges_Click(sender As System.Object, e As     System.EventArgs) Handles SaveChanges.Click

    Dim con As New MySqlConnection("host = localhost; username = root; password = 1234; database = logindb")
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE login SET username = '" & ChangeUsername.Text & "' and password = '" & ChangePassword.Text & "' and Security_Question1 ='" & ChangeSecQue1.Text & "' and Security_Question2 = '" & ChangeSecQue2.Text & "' and Security_Answer1 = '" & ChangeSecAns1.Text & "' and Security_Answer2 = '" & ChangeSecAns2.Text & "' "
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Saved Changes!")
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Use a comma instead of `and` in your update query

Comment: And a `WHERE` clause

Comment: @Verdolino That's an entirely different issue

Comment: @MariCz shanyour has kindly provided what I suggested as an answer

Comment: So we'll just tackle that in the next question when all the logins have been changed? ok

Comment: Thank you! It worked! :)

Comment: @MariCz this will update *all* your logins to the same value. If this is what you intended, fine. Otherwise, you need to use `WHERE` to target specific login(s). See http://www.dofactory.com/sql/update

Comment: Always use SQL parameters instead of concatenating bits of string.   Your code will crash on a name like `D'Artagnan`.  Never ever store passwords as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

change your update statement:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE login SET username = '" & ChangeUsername.Text & "' ,password = '" & ChangePassword.Text & "' ,Security_Question1 ='" & ChangeSecQue1.Text & "' ,Security_Question2 = '" & ChangeSecQue2.Text & "' ,Security_Answer1 = '" & ChangeSecAns1.Text & "' ,Security_Answer2 = '" & ChangeSecAns2.Text & "' "
```

Comment: No where clause...so your solution is to update every single record in the table to the exact same values while simultaneously leaving it wide open to sql injection..?